# How to set shape_invariants in Tensorflows while_loop for tensors that increase in size

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop

In my simple example the input has initially the shape (3,) but once through the body() it will have (3,2). Neither of those work as shape_invariants. Any idea how to specify the shape of a tensor if it changes in the body() of a while loop?

```
import tensorflow as tf

repeats = 2

def body(inputs, i, iter):
    outputs = tf.stack([inputs,inputs],axis=1)    
    return [outputs, i+1, iter]

def cond(inputs, i, iter ):
    return tf.less(i,repeats)

i = tf.constant(0)
iter = tf.constant(repeats)     

inputs = tf.get_variable("my_variable", initializer=tf.constant([1, 2, 3]))


with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(inputs.get_shape())
    outputs = tf.while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars=[inputs,i, iter],shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape([3,None]),i.get_shape(),iter.get_shape()])
    print(len(outputs))
    print(sess.run(outputs))
```

> ValueError: The shape invariant specified for my_variable/read:0 is
>   not compatible with the initial shape of the loop variable. It enters
>   the loop with shape (3,), but the specified shape invariant is (3, ?).

Comment: Have you tried to define the input as a tensor with shape (3, None) instead of (3,)? In the case you didn't, you could try to use tf.expand_dims() whenever the input is (3,)

Comment: If you just want to repeat the contents of a tensor, use [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile). Besides that, if you want to do something like that in a loop, you should either reshape `input` to `(3, 1)` and use [`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) instead of [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) (and have shape invariant `(3, None)`), or use a [`tf.TensorArray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray).